# Modifying text in EditText after text typed

Tags: android, android-edittext

Suppose I have an `EditText` view in an activity. I want to modify the text in `EditText` after it had been entered. For example, after I put `"Andrew"` in the `EditText` it automatically changes the text to `"Mr. Andrew"`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using a `TextWatcher` to listen for changes in the `EditText`. However, as [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher#afterTextChanged(android.text.Editable)) states

> It is legitimate to make further changes to s from this callback, but be careful not to get yourself into an infinite loop, because any changes you make will cause this method to be called again recursively.

Simply adding the string will be a sure way to trigger a `StackOverflowError`, because `onAfterTextChanged()` will be called recursively in an infinte loop.

Therefor, you need to check if the text already begins with the string that you want to add, and only add it if it's not already there. Something like this might work:

```
EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String prefix = "Mr. ";
        String text = s.toString();

        if( text.length() < prefix.length() || !text.substring(0, prefix.length()).equals(prefix) )
            s.insert(0, prefix);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [`addTextChangedListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) to the your EditText and override the `afterTextChange()` like below

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
      //get the text in the edittext first
      String name = s.getText().toString();
      //then concatenate it with "Mr. " and setText again
      s.setText("Mr. " + name);
   }

   @Override    
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int count, int after) {
   }

   @Override    
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
     int before, int count) {}
  });
```